# Consolidating files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to consolidate all Excel files that are in specific folder. I created an Input Box for the Path of the folder where I have files to merge. Then I have formula for the Filename and that formula does not work. It gives value `Filename=""`. Why does it happen? How can it be fixed?

```
Dim Path as String
Dim Filename as String

Path = InputBox("Paste the path of the folder with files to consolidate")

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
```

Comment: What does `Path` evaluate to? Are you sure it's finding the right location

Comment: And are there files present at the path of those types?

Comment: Did you assign Filename with    Filename = Dir before looping again?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Excel's own folder picker? Try this code.

```
Function PickedFolder() As String

    Dim Dlg As FileDialog
    Dim Ffn As String

    Ffn = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    Set Dlg = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Dlg
        .Title = "Select the folder to consolidate"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .InitialFileName = Ffn
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = True Then PickedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

The function returns the path the user selects. You can enter it in your text box or proceed directly to consolidate the files found in it.